# Javascript Upload image and overlay a mask image that user can download then

Tags: javascript, jquery

So my question is, if it's possible to let a user upload an image of there face and output the same picture but with an overlay on top of it. So they could right click and save the image or hit a download button? All this needs to be client-sided.

Something similar to the french flags on facebook. It's been awhile since i have coded so can it be done with javascript?

Answer (score 1):

My dude, here's what I think you can do. Using HTML5 add the image overlay to a canvas, and add the uploaded image to a canvas. Add the watermark canvas to the image canvas using `ctx.drawImage(watermark_canvas,0,0)`. ctx.drawImage() lets you add a canvas to another canvas. Once those canvases are combined you can get a base64 encoded data of the combined canvas by calling this `canvas.toDataURL()`